# Google webfont rendering poorly on IE7 and IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, google-webfonts

I have been trying hard to figure out why does the following "Fiddle" renders so poorly under Internet Explorer 7 and 8:

http://jsfiddle.net/5aFAX/

**Internet Explorer 9**

[image: Internet Explorer 9]

**Internet Explorer 7 and 8**

[image: Internet Explorer 7 and Internet Explorer 8]

Under Internet Explorer 9 the font renders just fine (almost the same as under Chrome and Firefox). However, under Internet Explorer 7 and 8 the rendering is just plainly horrible. Is there any way I can fix this behaviour under these browsers without changing the typeface (Raleway)?

Answer (score 2):

IE is just poor at rendering fonts (poor with most things to be honest).
However usually it is really bad when there is Opacity in play, I can see in your fiddle you aren't using opacity, but you are using the font's weight.

try using `px` instead of `em` and try not to set the weight of the font

Hope that helps